# Magento2 - 2 catalogs with the same SKU products

Tags: multistore, sku, multi-website

Is it possible to create 2 independent catalogs that will have products with the same SKU?

Store1 - catalog1 (SKU1, SKU2, SKU3)
Store2 - catalog2 (SKU1, SKU2, SKU3)

Or it's never going to work? SKU must be unique even for different websites/stores?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different stores and different categories and can assign the same products in different categories.
SKU is unique. Can create different products with same sku